# Counting crossings

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, catalan-numbers

It is possible to count the number of non-crossing diagrams including $k$ bridges by using Catalan numbers. For instance in Fig [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d6Iu.png), I show the 5 possible diagrams obtained for $k = 3$ bridges, which equals $Cat(3)$.

[image: Possible diagrams without crossings with $k$ = 3]

In general
$$ N_{n.c.} (k) = Cat(k) $$
with $N_{n.c.}(k)$ the number of non-crossing diagrams with $k$ bridges.

My question is: is there a way to count the number of diagrams with a fixed number $\alpha$ of crossings: $N(k, \alpha)$? For instance, for $k=2$, we have
$$ N(2, 0) = N_{n.c.}(2) = 2\;, \qquad N(2,1) = 1 $$
which are represented in Fig[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5AyR.png). Note that I exclude degenerate cases where more than two bridges cross at the same point. Also starting and ending points of different bridges cannot coincide.

[image: Diagrams with $k=2$ and $\alpha 0 ,1 $ crossings]

The total contributions from diagrams with an arbitrary number of crossings $\alpha$ is also easy to compute:
$$ N_{tot}(k) = \sum_{\alpha\geq 0} N(k, \alpha) = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!} $$

But what about the single coefficients $N(k, \alpha)$?

Comment: How do you count crossings of more than two bridges in a single point? Or is this not allowed?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, move slightly one circle and you will have the same number of crosses, but without the intersection.

Comment: yes this coincident crossings are not considered, as they can always be reduced to other cases moving slightly one circle.

Comment: @AlexanderAgüero How does this not matter? One time you have one point, the other time you have three points associated with an intersection. It is not clear on how to count this or if it is allowed if not explicitely stated.

Comment: Ok simply multiple crossings are not allowed so they do not need to be counted. I have specified it in the text now to avoid confusion.

Comment: Question is too ambiguous as currently phrased, I think. For example: http://i.imgur.com/Xcbbx5n.png -- there are many possible setups (among several more I didn't include there). What are the restrictions?

Comment: The starting/ending points of different bridges cannot coincide. They can only cross midway and as I stated more clearly now, I am excluding multiple crossings of several bridges at the same point.

Comment: There are still some more problem, but I think by stating that the bridges are semi-circles with not interesecting end points you could exclude the most ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2002 [I gave an expression in alt.math.recreational](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.math.recreational/MLE2FnHT2VI/C3q5AkBJOocJ), translated to your $k$ and $\alpha$ as

$$N(k,\alpha)=\sum_{j} (-1)^j { (k-j)(k-j+1)/2-1-\alpha \choose k-1}  \left({2k \choose j}-{2k \choose j-1}\right)$$

where $j$ is such that $0 \le j \le k$ and  $(k-j)(k-j+1) \ge 2(k + \alpha)$

[OEIS A067311](https://oeis.org/A067311) has more information, as this is equivalent to counting handshakes across a table and the number of crossings as illustrated in

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you know closed form for the generating function of this expression?

Comment: @abenassen - I am afraid not.  Some of the links from the OEIS page discuss generating functions but not obviously to me in a closed form